# Why is preprocessor usage less common in languages other than C/C++/ObjC?

Tags: c#, java, c, preprocessor

I've been a Java and VB.Net programmer for about 4 years and a C# programmer for about 6 months.  I've also used a bunch of dynamic languages like Perl, Python, PHP, and JavaScript.

I've never had a need for a preprocessor.

My question is: why do you see such extensive use of preprocessors in C, C++, and Objective-C but rarely (or never) see it in languages like Java, C#, or Scala?

Comment: We learned from C. With C/C++/Objective-C, they got the C compiler right then just built on top of it because it was easier that way.  More recent languages were just designed better from the ground up.  Most people I know with a C background that have moved on are terrified of pre-processors.  Not good for speed, screws up your design, harms comprehension.  No advantage except it lets you write worse code--why would anyone copy that on purpose?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652788/what-is-the-worst-real-world-macros-pre-processor-abuse-youve-ever-come-across and http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/06/347666.aspx :)

Comment: I have several C++ dsp programs where every cycle counts (yes, really). The preprocessor helps me quite a bit during optimization. I don't use it for anything else. I LOVE it. You couldn't pry it out of my hands. Have you done a lot of real time dsp programming in those dynamic languages? Remember that no matter how many kinds of programming you've done, you've just scratched the surface of the kinds of programming that _can_ be done.

Comment: @Nosredna: Oh I completely agree that, just because I haven't had a need for the preprocessor, I would never need it.  I was just curious as to why you see it used so much more in C and C-superset languages.

Comment: I personally really like the preprocessor for C/C++ testing. I find it's really easy to write / extend a test suite using the preprocessor than it is to do similar things in other languages. I personally miss the preprocessor when using other languages. (Of course, this, using `__FILE__/__LINE__` in logging, and conditional compilation are just about the only times I have to use the preprocessor.)

Comment: I should also point out that C# does have something similar to the C preprocessor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/. Although more limited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know Objective-C, so my answer will be about contrasting the use of the preprocessor in C and C++.

The preprocessor was originally necessary for C for several reasons.  If I remember correctly, originally C did not have constants, so `#define` was needed to avoid magic numbers.  Prior to 1999 C did not have inline functions, so again `#define` was used to create macros or "pseudo-functions" to save the overhead of a function call, while keeping code structured.  C also doesn't have run-time or compile-time polymorphism, so `#ifdef`s were needed for conditional compilation.  Compilers were typically not smart enough to optimize away unreachable code, so, again, `#ifdef`s were used to insert debugging or diagnostic code.

Using the preprocessor in C++ is a throwback to C, and is generally frowned upon.  Language features, such as constants, inline functions, and templates can be used in most situations where in C you would have used the preprocessor.

The few cases where the use of a pre-processor in C++ is acceptable or even necessary include the guards for the header files, to prevent the same header from being included multiple times, `#ifdef __cplusplus` to use the same header for both C and C++, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` for logging, and a few others.

The preprocessor is also often used for platform-specific definitions, although [C++ Gotchas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125185) by Stephen Dewhurst advises having separate include directories for the platform specific definitions, and using them in separate build configurations for each platform.

Comment: That's not the only time preprocessor use in C++ is considered OK. Other uses widely (if not universally) considered OK include outputting `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in logging, the Boost FOREACH macro, checking compiler feature support (including the classic `#ifdef __cplusplus // extern "C" {// #endif`), platform-specific definitions (e.g. where you need `__declspec` in MSVC and `__attribute__` in GCC), defining NDEBUG before including <cassert>,...

Answer (score 11):

The reason why you don't see the preprocessor used in Java, C#, or Scala is that those languages obviously don't have one.

One of the common uses for the C preprocessor is to help provide platform-specific code. Since C (I'm including C++ and Objective-C here) is a low-level language that needs to interface with the operating system directly, in portable code there must necessarily be different sections of the code compiled for different operating systems. You can find extensive examples of this sort of thing in a mature, highly portable code base such as [zlib](http://zlib.net).

As a simple example, to close a network socket one must do something like this (at some level, this can certainly be wrapped in a function but it has to exist somewhere):

```
#ifdef WIN32
    closesocket(s);
#else
    close(s);
#endif
```

Newer languages that run on VMs do not need the different platform-specific sections of code, and can be written against the single, portable standard library.

The preprocessor also provides a way to define constants in C, which are provided by other, better, language features in newer languages.

In The Design and Evolution of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup stated that he wanted to remove the dependency on the preprocessor in C++, but was not successful.

Comment: "The reason why you don't see the preprocessor ...is that those languages ...don't have one."  !! excellent!

Comment: A real language could examine the WIN32 variable, see that it's final and generate the correct path inline.  There is virtually no use for preprocessors in a modern language.

Comment: Ironically enough (if I'm not mistaken), Bjarne's predecessor to C++, C with Classes, was essentially a macro layer on C.

Comment: Yes, the original C++ was implemented as a preprocessor.  Objective-C may still be a preprocessor--and a very simple one at that.  It really does virtually nothing but keep track of a bunch of symbols and insert address pointers into your code.

Comment: From what little I've read it seems that Bjarne is fairly adamant that C++ was never implemented as a preprocessor. It was a fully formed compiler that generated c code not assembler. As Andrew mentions, C with Classes was apparently implemented as a preprocessor.

Comment: Yes, Obj-C would just need to grep a bunch of @ signs and brackets ;)

Comment: The original 1980s implementations of C++ were based on a special AT&T preprocessor called cfront.  The back end was the C compiler, cc.  Likewise the original 1980's Objective-C implementation from StepStone, Inc (Brad Cox's company) was a preprocessor in front of cc.  In both cases cpp was run first, then cfront or the Objective C preprocessor, and then the standard cc toolchain.  This allowed both languages to be ported easily to many platforms.

Comment: C# does have a preprocessor: http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Preprocessor_Directives

Comment: C# supports #if debug / #endif and #region/#endregion, but they're not *pre-processor* directives.

Answer (score 9):

Every language needs a mechanism for **separate compilation**.   Ideally the language distinguishes interfaces from implementations, and a module depends only on the interfaces of the modules it exports.  (See, e.g., Ada, Clu, Modula, and so on.)

C has no language construct for interfaces or implementations.  Because it's vital that different .c files share a single view of interfaces, the programming discipline evolved of putting declarations (i.e., interfaces) in .h files and sharing those declarations/interfaces using textual inclusion (`#include`).  In principle, `#define` and `#ifdef` could be dispensed with, but `#include` could not.

Nowadays language designers recognize that textual inclusion is no way to run a railroad, so languages tend to run either to separately compiled interfaces (Ada, Modula, OCaml), to compiler-generated interfaces (Haskell), or to dynamic systems that guarantee interface consistency (Java, Smalltalk).  With such a mechanism, there is no need for a preprocessor, and plenty of reasons not to have one (think *source-code analysis* and *debugging*).

Comment: +1 Your answer seems to be the most neutral and informative one here. I applaud you.

Comment: I think `#if` and friends are still needed for platform specific code in C/C++.

Answer (score 4):

Because the design and aims of these languages are not the same.

C was built with the preprocessor in mind as a powerful tool, it was used to implement very basic stuff(such as inclusion guards) and developers were able to use it to either optimize their code through macros or to optionally include/exclude certain blocks of code in addition to other things.
C++ inherited most of C's idioms, macros are not used for speed anymore(because inline was introduced) but it's still used for plenty of things, see the post [What are preprocessor macros good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265951/what-are-preprocessor-macros-good-for)

Answer (score 3):

Because Gosling and Heilsberg both understand the perils and technical debt incurred with the misuse of preprocessing!

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessing is very, very common in the Java world.  It's used to compensate for the language's lack of adequate built-in abstraction facilities, which would otherwise lead to endless copied-and-pasted boilerplate code.

The reason many people don't realise this is true is that in the Java world it's called "code generation" rather than "preprocessing", because "preprocessor" sounds like nasty old C, while "code generation" sounds like a professional tool that efficiates mature enterprise processes.  It's still preprocessing, though, even if you have to pay a fortune for an incompatible non-standard proprietary tool to do it, instead of just using facilities built into the language.

Comment: What a brilliant answer, I really wish I could give it more than one up Vote!

Comment: Yup, sometimes I really miss the preprocessor when using Java

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with what seems to be the going consensus where that cpp is un-necessary in modern languages. I have a lot of cases where I've got 3 slightly different versions of the same program, and I want to be able to make a bunch of changes for each version. With CPP, I can put them all in #if #else blocks, and I can define the #if at the compile line. in Java, I need to create some sort of static global and initialize it at compile time. I never got that to work properly.

Comment: @Brian: Eww!  I'm not surprised it didn't work properly!  A better solution in Java would be to use subclasses or the "Strategy" pattern to separate out the differences between the versions.

Comment: But if the differences are 10 lines strewn across a class, or worse multiple classes? that's a whole lot of effort.

Comment: @Brian: you can't win this argument. This is Java, so more classes => Better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Modern languages have the preprocessor included in the language itself! For C++, the preprocessor is needed only for module management and conditional inclusion for example which is very useful.

I believe it was a separate tool, because compilers were not one-tool as we know them today. I heard that very old C compilers used to produce the tokens to files, then do the rest of compilation in separate stages. The main reason I can think of is that memory and other resources were very scarce compared to what we have today.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor in C and C++ has two different functions

- pulling files together in the build process - languages 
  like Java et al. have their own mechanisms like import to do this
- performing textual substitutions - this is still needed to certain extent in C, but C++ can do it (for the most part) better using templates

So both C and C++ need it for the first of these, but C++ can junk it for the second, although it can be useful even in C++ - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265951/what-are-preprocessor-macros-good-for) from earlier today.

Comment: certain things, like using `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` in logging or test suites, can't be done easily without the preprocessor (and I'm sad when I have to do them in another language that doesn't have a preprocessor).

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure that the modern language is written in C or C++, and in that implementation itself there are macros. You need them to deal with operating system differences for one thing. The dynamic / higher-level languages wrap, and hide many of the things that somewhere at the bottom, you need macros for.

Also, macros are used for speed sometimes. In dynamic languages, speed isn't as crucial.

Answer (score 0):

You should look a bit more closely at Perl. Perl supports [source filters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html), which are basically custom Perl pre-processors written in Perl :)

Answer (score 0):

Java was designed to avoid several features that make C++ hard to use.

C# copy ( or inherit ) most of the design decision from Java.

Higher level programming languages avoid this kind of low level artifacts.